# How to run asynchronous task using GWT with App Engine?

Tags: java, gwt, djangoappengine

Hi
What would be a best solution to initiate the task on App Engine?
What I am trying to achieve is to send email to user every 6, 16, 30 days after the registration. This service should run independently from the app (so not user initiated).

What would be the best way to achieve this with App Engine and GWT (Java)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the Scheduled Task API ([Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html) or [Java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron.html)) or Task Queue API ([Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) or [Java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/)) depending on your use case. Perhaps send the initial e-mail using the task queue and then the follow-up e-mails could be generated via scheduled tasks.